# How to generate transparent thumbnail in symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have use code to generate transferent thumbnail but I am getting one error, error is

```
"ImageMagick convert command not found" while generating thumbnail.
```

And My code is:

```
$thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(800, 510, true, false,80, 'sfImageMagickAdapter', array('extract' => 1, 'convert' => 'convert-flatten'));
```

And I have also use this code:

```
$thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(32, 32, true, false,80, 'sfImageMagickAdapter', array('extract' => 1, 'flatten' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct($maxWidth = null,
                            $maxHeight = null,
                            $scale = true,
                            $inflate = true,
                            $quality = 75,
                            $adapterClass = null,
                            $adapterOptions = array()
                           )
```

and below class create for thumbnail create

```
$thumbnail = new sfThumbnail(32, 32, true, false,80, 'sfImageMagickAdapter', array('extract' => 1, 'flatten' => true));
```

Comment: Thanks Mitesh for reply.
But I have used same code for generating transferent thumbnail and thumbnail is generating with white background

Answer (score 0):

To use `sfImageMagickAdapter`, you need to install binaries from http://www.imagemagick.org, as is stated in the documentation. If the `convert` command is not on path, specify its full path in `$adapterOptions` array, same for `identify`:

```
array('convert' => '/path/to/convert', 'identify' => '/path/to/identify')
```